# PARALLEL_MIN_PERCENT affect parallel execution

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, parallel-processing

The document([Oracle document 1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams185.htm)) said

> PARALLEL_MIN_PERCENT lets you specify the minimum percentage of the requested number of parallel execution processes required for parallel execution. Setting this parameter ensures that parallel operations will not execute unless adequate resources are available. The default value of 0 means that no minimum percentage of processes has been set.
>
> Consider the following settings:
>
> PARALLEL_MIN_PERCENT = 50
>
> PARALLEL_MIN_SERVERS = 5
>
> PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS = 10
>
> If 8 of the 10 parallel execution processes are busy, only 2 processes are available. If you then request a query with a degree of parallelism of 8, the minimum 50% will not be met.

another document([oracle document 2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/parallel004.htm)) said

> Specifies the minimum percentage of requested parallel execution processes required for parallel execution. With the default value of 0, a parallel statement executes serial if no parallel server processes are available.

My question is in the example settings the document provided if the minimum 50% is not met. the query is queued or execute serially or has an error like *insufficient parallel query slaves available*??

Comment: This is an educated guess, as I've not been able to test yet. But I think it will depend if you have parallel statement queueing enabled. This is enabled when you have AUTO DOP enabled; or if you set the parameter "_parallel_statement_queueing"=TRUE.